# XCopy encounters a sharing violation, how to handle

Tags: windows-7, robocopy, xcopy

I'm using `xcopy` for copying large bundles of files. One thing I particularly like about `xcopy` is the `/F` switch which shows all source and destination files, paths included, something like:

```
xcopy /E /Y /F D:\Temp_Folder\test_origin\* D:\Temp_Folder\test_dest\
D:\Temp\origin\B_Normal\blabla.txt -> D:\Temp\dest\B_Normal\blabla.txt
D:\Temp\origin\B_Normal\B.A\normal.txt -> D:\Temp\dest\B_Normal\B.A\normal.txt
D:\Temp\origin\B_Normal\B.B\drawing.bmp -> D:\Temp\dest\B_Normal\B.B\drawing.bmp
D:\Temp\origin\C_Fill_with_empty\empty.bmp -> D:\Temp\dest\C_Fill_with_empty\empty.bmp
D:\Temp\origin\C_Fill_with_empty\empty.txt -> D:\Temp\dest\C_Fill_with_empty\empty.txt
5 File(s) copied
```

However there seem to be some issues:

```
D:\Temp\origin>tree /F /A
...
D:.
+---A_Empty
+---B_Normal
|   |   blabla.txt
|   |
|   +---B.A
|   |       normal.txt
|   |
|   \---B.B
|           Drawing.bmp
|
\---C_Fill_with_empty
    |   empty.bmp
    |   empty.txt
    |
    \---empty
```

As you can see, the directories `D:\Temp\origin\A_Empty\` and `D:\Temp\origin\C_Fill_with_empty\empty\` seem not having been copied (empty files seem to be copied, not empty directories).

This however is not true: in the destination folder, the directories `A_empty` and `C_Fill_with_empty\empty` are there, but the `/F` switch only showed the files which were copied, so the copy of empty directories is done, but not shown. (In my original post, I thought the empty directories were not copied)

Most important, I don't understand the meaning of the `/C` switch, which says

> Continues copying even if errors occur.

Last night the `xcopy` result of a bunch copy was an error message:

```
\\nas\<Complicated_Directory_Tree>\<file1>.gif -> G:\<Complicated_Directory_Tree>\<file1>.gif
\\nas\<Complicated_Directory_Tree>\<file2>.gif -> G:\<Complicated_Directory_Tree>\<file2>.gif
Sharing violation
```

I would like to avoid this irreproducible error message, using a retry mechanism, but I don't know how the `/C` switch will behave: will it behave as a "Retry" or an "Ignore"? (This question has already been asked by other people, but those people received the advise to change to `robocopy`, but as mentioned in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744335/how-do-i-force-robocopy-to-overwrite-files), also this seems not so error-prone).

Does anybody know how to force a retry mechanism?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well maybe the reason for using robocopy is that it doesn't have this error? I know robocopy by default retries something like 100,000 times.

Comment: A billion retries won't do any good if the error persists.

Comment: Just for your information: I've modified the post as the issue of the empty directories has been solved in the meanwhile.

Comment: Already posted the solution for that.

Comment: @Overmind: indeed you're right. Unfortunately the problem is irreproducible and it happens on different files, apparently random. I believe that there is some process, doing something very shortly on a file (like taking a backup or so), and at this particular moment `xcopy` has a problem. Simply retrying (possibly after waiting one second) might overcome this issue.

Comment: A retry example here: http://lichao.net/eblog/how-to-use-loop-function-in-dos-to-re-try-command-200909380.html  ; you can use something similar + the timeout command (to delay the retry how many seconds you consider necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  **/E**   parameter copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. Just add that, and the problem is solved.

The **/C** parameter continues copying even if errors occur. That should skip any problems.

To elaborate, the **/c** ignores the error and continues the copy process with the next valid file.

If you want retries on errors (although not recommended) you could use a WHILE loop in the batch file for that (useful commands: **IF ERRORLEVEL** = and **timeout**). [Example](http://lichao.net/eblog/how-to-use-loop-function-in-dos-to-re-try-command-200909380.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I've decided not to use it: I'm working with batchfiles, using more than 100 xcopy commands. In top of that, the xcopy commands contain difficult directory structures, duplicating those endangers the quality of the batchfiles. So I've decided to go for another approach: the files which are causing problems are located on one specific network location and I've asked my network administrator to put a file monitor on every file there. Once the problem occurs again, we'll compare the file monitoring result with the timestamps in the result log of my batchfile.

Comment: That was a good idea; monitoring parameters is the first step that should be taken. Better know the cause instead of bypassing it.